# how to start mongodb on remote server EC2?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Am new to mongodb. I have installed it on my pc with wamp server and it is working fine. Now am trying to connect with EC2 remotely. 
I have gone through [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) . But still am not getting to connect.

Here is the code

```
[ec2-user@ip-162-31-45-45 ~]$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-09-07T06:07:44.158+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=27743 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-45-55
2014-09-07T06:07:44.158+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2014-09-07T06:07:44.158+0000 [initandlisten] git version:  xxxxx
2014-09-07T06:07:44.158+0000 [initandlisten] build info:  xxxxx
2014-09-07T06:07:44.158+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-09-07T06:07:44.158+0000 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-09-07T06:07:44.163+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-09-07T06:07:44.163+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-09-07T06:07:44.331+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2014-09-07T06:07:44.331+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
2014-09-07T06:07:44.331+0000 [initandlisten] now exiting
2014-09-07T06:07:44.331+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2014-09-07T06:07:44.331+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.331+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.332+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.332+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.332+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.332+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.340+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.340+0000 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-09-07T06:07:44.340+0000 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.340+0000 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2014-09-07T06:07:44.344+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-09-07T06:07:44.344+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now



[ec2-user@ip-162-31-45-45 ~]$ sudo service mongod start
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

By installing all these from [This](http://jonathanhui.com/install-mongodb-amazon-linux) was solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the address is already in use. Are you sure it's not already running?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to know that it is running or not. Am unable to run from browser

Comment: Just run the mongo command on the server - it should connect to the local server.

Comment: yes, $ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
>
But why am unable to run from browser

Comment: OK, great, so it's started, which was your original question. Now we need to figure out why you can't connect remotely. Firstly, is your security group setup to allow access? Secondly, is mongodb bound to all network interfaces, or just localhost?

Comment: i have copied my code under /var/www/html ec2-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. But am able to run normal html/php. Am unable to run mongodb under this

Comment: Firstly, is your security group setup to allow access?Secondly, is mongodb bound to all network interfaces, or just localhost? Means is there any other settings also ?

Comment: There should be a configuration file for mongod (maybe /etc/mongod.conf) that specifies a bind_ip. If that is set to 127.0.0.1 your server only listen to the local loopback address.

Comment: @TeTeT  yes, it was only bind_ip=127.0.0.1
#port=27017 on mongod.conf file

Comment: You can bind mongod to all addresses via bind_ip, but make sure the databases are secured somehow with login and password. Otherwise anybody can connect and get your data.

Comment: @TeTeT thank you. Can you provide any link here to connect mongodb from php here

Comment: Never touched that, I'd use the mongo.org language center, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/